# Camel: JSonPath seems change context when performing search

Tags: json, apache-camel, jsonpath

Have some JSON:

```
{
  metadata:{
    result_count: 3,
  },

  search_results: [
   {...},
   {...},
   {...}
  ]
}
```

When doing

```
.setHeader("result_count").jsonpath("$.metadata.result_count")
.setHeader("result").jsonpath("$.search_results[0]")
```

getting

```
Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Property ['search_results'] not found in path $
```

when changing the order:

```
.setHeader("result").jsonpath("$.search_results[0]")
.setHeader("result_count").jsonpath("$.metadata.result_count")
```

getting

```
Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Property ['metadata'] not found in path $
```

How to solve?

Comment: Is your message body of type `InputStream` or of type `String`?

Comment: I think it's InputStream. Think I should `converBodyTo(String.class)` prior to `jsonpath`?

Comment: Either that or enable stream caching.